# Matlab Plotting custom constellation along with decision regions

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, constellation-diagram

How do I create a custom constellation along with decision regions in Matlab, any help is greatly appreciated[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is your difficulty? A constellation is just a set of points, which can be arbitrary, and the decision regions is just the [Voronoi diagram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html) of the set.

Comment: @MBaz ... in the ML case, yes.

Comment: Added pictures with more details on the project! I think this is MAP case

Comment: @DaleGribble so, what's the specific question you're asking here? we can't be writing your code...

Comment: What have you tried so far? People on here will not just answer a question like this without something more specific, especially since it appears to be a part of your course work. Do you understand what a constellation is? Are you unsure how to plot? Do you know what decision regions are? Do you know how to plot those?

Comment: I am a noob with Matlab in general, we aren't taught it in school nor given any examples, yet expected to use it to solve problems.. With no help from Teachers Assistant.. I would appreciate an example of how to plot a custom constellation, and its associated decision region, while having maximum min for constant Es. Im not looking to be spoon-fed with solutions, but any help and examples would be greatly appreciated. I am super lost on how to start

Comment: Designing the custom constellation is your project...so nobody will help you on that here. But for plotting a constellation, use "scatter" in MATLAB or there are other ways from the toolboxes: https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/scatter-plots.html

Comment: how would I turn my x and y values into a signal for me too pass though a AWGN channel ? So far I have 
M = 4;
x_vals=[1,-1,1,-1]; 
v_vals=[1,1,-1,-1]; 
Voronoi(x_vals,y_vals); 
signal= [x_vals,y_vals]; % I think this is wrong
received_signal = awgn(signal,10,'measured');
scatterplot(received_signal, M);

Comment: these are not x and y values, but real and imaginary part of your complex constellation points; It's unclear from your question where exactly your problem lies therein. As @Engineer says: this is not a place where we write your Matlab code, it's a place where we help you understand your signal processing so you can do that on your own.